# learn C# for Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin-studio

I want to build apps using Xamarin in C#. But unfortunately I don't know C#. I have tried looking around on Google but nothing really helpful comes along. If anyone uses Xamarin to make C# apps can you please tell me where you learn it. Thank you.

Comment: Xarmin has sample apps on their website. This being said this is outside of the scope of Stack Overflow to answer these questions.

Comment: This is a request for external resources...

Comment: You google'd for Xamarin beginner examples and got nothing?  I don't think anyone is going to be able to help you

Comment: Amazon has a wide variety of books you can purchase.  Or go to the library.  Or check out the literally millions of free online resources.  Or the hundreds of samples and walkthroughs on Xamarin's site.

Answer (score 3):

**Microsoft Virtaul Academy**(MVA) is a great place to learn new stuffs

• Get the resources you need for **Xamarin** here: [Tools](https://mva.microsoft.com/colleges/xamarin)

• Learn **Xamarin for Absolute Beginners**: [Learn Xamarin](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-US/training-courses/xamarin-for-absolute-beginners-16182)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.learnvisualstudio.net If you want to get a good foothold, I got my first job using this site. Bob is great.

Also, channel9 has this: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C-Sharp-Fundamentals-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners which is great... cause it's also Bob.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple C# classes available at udemy.com.  Or if  you want to pay membership fees, you can also join pluralsight.com.  The membership is just $29.99.